# Question on the complement of a set of integers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S = \cup_{p, prime } (p\mathbb{Z}) = \cup_{p} \{ pz : z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. What is $\mathbb{Z} \setminus S$? I was thinking it is $\{\pm 1\}$, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think you're right

Comment: Is that an unequivocal answer? The reason why I am asking this is because I was looking at a question which said that $S^{c} = \{\pm 1\}$ implies there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes... I don't see why that's important though. The only important fact is that the integers are a PID, with all of the prime ideals generated by primes.